# Gson Unicode characters not displaying properly in response to front-end

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson, unicode-string

I have a service that returns a json object in which the summary field has unicode characters which are not being displayed properly. The unicode characters in this string are not displaying properly in the response. Example response:

```
summary: "A boyfriend and girlfriend?s deaths in Arlington, being investigated as a murder-suicide, shock relatives."
```

The single quote in the word girlfriend's is appearing as a ? character. How would I fix this issue? The relevant code is:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFilePath);
BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
gson= new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
RecommendationResponseDto recommendationResponseDto;
recommendationResponseDto = gson.fromJson(buffered,RecommendationResponseDto.class);
```

A sample of the response from an external service which returns the unicode summary handled by aforementioned gson object code is as follows:

```
u'A boyfriend and girlfriend\u2019s deaths in Arlington, being investigated as a murder-suicide, shock relatives.'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `FileReader`. Instead, explicitly specify a character set:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```

See also, a [blog post I wrote](https://publicobject.com/2012/10/03/don-t-use-filereader-or-filewriter/) on the subject.

Comment: The fix still didn't work. The unicode is still appearing as ? in the json response. Do you know what else could be the problem? Or is there any other specific information I could provide that would help narrow down the error? Also would you suggest using Jackson over Gson as I've heard (although this might be a matter of opinion) that it handles unicode better?

Comment: Jackson & Gson both handle Unicode correctly. You need to make sure you're using the same character set to read the file that you're using to write it. If you're getting `?` characters when reading it as UTF-8, it's possible that it's encoded with a different charset. Figure out what that is, and use it. (Possibly `ISO-8859-1`).